# Ajax data Option if no button disabled

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button

I needed help with my button to be disabled that if the option selected if "No" it be disabled and if "Yes" it be enabled. I'm using my AJAX to call for the option.

This is my HTML code for the `<option>` and `<button>`:

```html
<label for="select-Require-CDS" class="col-form-label">Require CDS</label> <br/>

<select class="select-Require-CDS custom-select-sm col-6" id="select-Require-CDS" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
</select>

<div class="invalid-feedback">
   Please select a valid option .
</div>

<button id="select-Yes-No" style="margin-left: 10px; ">Select</button>
```

This is my AJAX code:

```js
$.ajax({
    // The url that you're going to post. This is the url that you're going to put to call the backend api,
    // in this case, it's  https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get (production env)
    url: "https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get",
    
    // The HTTP method that you're planning to use i.e
    // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. In this case it's a get method, so we'll use GET
    method: "GET",
    
    // In this case, we are going to use headers as 
    headers: {
        // The query you're planning to call; i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
        query: "RequireGet()",
  
       // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
        apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
      
        for (let option of data)
        {
            $('#select-Require-CDS').append($('<option>', {
                value: option.RequireOption,
                text: option.RequireOption
            }));
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And this is how my JSON response is:

```
[
    {
        "RequireOption": "No"
    },
    {
        "RequireOption": "Yes"
    }
]
```

So my website display it be like this

[image]

Now how can I say that I select option as "No" the button is disabled but if "Yes" is enabled?

[image]

How that if no it be disabled as well ?

Comment: listen for change of the select and if the value is No then disable. Or if you start with the button disabled then enable on Yes (it is the same actually). Where do you get stuck at? you didn't show any attempt on this!

Comment: sry i not very good at this how can i write it with if else ? where to i edit it at inside the ajax ?

Comment: If nothing is selected when the page loads, you should start with the button disabled. However, if you only have one option that enables the button you could probably get away with just a checkbox. Either way, as @LelioFaieta said, listen for the change and adjust accordingly.

Comment: i have fix the issue is how to if text: option.RequireOption
 = No it disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#select-Require-CDS').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()=='Yes'){
        $('#select-Yes-No').attr('disabled',false) //button is now enabled
    }else{
        $('#select-Yes-No').attr('disabled',true) //button is now disabled
    }
});
```

This is an handler listening for change on the select. Based on what is selected then it adapt the button availability. It is untested but should do the trick.

I have used `.on` because you are adding the attributes later with ajax (later = after dom ready) so `.change` will not work on these options